# Best Practice: Documentation Standards

Tags: .net, documentation, standards

Here is the issue, I need to find/think of documentation standards for our team. We have several needs, we need documentation standards for ***Requirements Documentation***, ***Technical Documentation*** - **for projects** and **Code Style Documentation** - **for developers** which would cover how developers should name, and organize the project's code (should he use regions? How should naming look? etc.), I know it can vary from project to project, but maybe there are some kind of standards for that. Currently each developer writes it as he imagines, and that is not so good, because it is inconsistent, and with different styles etc.

I'm curious how you/your company does that. And maybe there is some kind of standards for that.

How it should look? What content should it include?  etc..

BTW we use .NET Technologies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See also the Microsoft Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx

Comment: I liked internal Microsoft coding guideline. Is there any full version? Or a similar document using the same rules?

Comment: I think that is the full version - I wouldn't expect a coding guideline to contain much more - our one at work is a similar length.

Comment: Looks really nice. But what about Technical and Requirements documentations ? any standards for them?

Comment: I've never seen any standards for Technical or Requirements documents - the level to which these are needed varies so much between projects - requirements for medical and safety critical projects may need to be documented to a different level to those for a simple business app.

Comment: 404. Link is dead, unfortunately. Someone brings new links, please...

Comment: I've removed the dead link. The Microsoft Design Guidelines link still works.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very good book: [Microsoft Manual of Style for Technical Publications](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=6074&locale=en-us#tab1).

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue, and turned to IEEE to find some standards. I found the following, which I have not yet read, but seems of relevance:

## General documentation standards

- [IEEE Standard for Information Technology--Systems Design--Software Design Descriptions](http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1016-2009.html)
- [IEEE Systems and software engineering -- Software life cycle processes](http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/12207-2008.html)
- [IEEE IEEE Trial-Use Standard--Adoption of ISO/IEC TR 15026-1:2010 Systems and Software Engineering--Systems and Software Assurance--Part 1: Concepts and Vocabulary](http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/15026-1-2011.html)

Other than those, there are also an excellent overview at [www.codingthearchitecture.com](http://www.codingthearchitecture.com/pages/book/software-architecture-document-guidelines.html)

## Coding style standards

Besides the very fine "Microsoft Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries" mentioned above, there are some very good arguments to be found in the [Linux Kernel Coding Style Guidelines](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle), even though the examples given there are in C.